# How to infer class from generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble with understanding how to call a generic entity service. The code below works but I need to maintain `getEntityClass()` on each bean which I believe is totally redundant.

```
public abstract class BaseEntityBean<T extends BaseEntity> extends BaseBean {

    protected void loadEntity(Class<T> entityClass, Long entityId) { // entityClass same as T
        T entity=genericEntityService.getEntity(entityClass, entityId);
    }
```

Let's not change the signature of the `genericEntityService.getEntity(Class, Long)`.

I would like to change the signature of `loadEntity` to `loadEntity(Long entityId)`.

How can I call `genericEntityService.getEntity(Class, Long)` within `loadEntity(Long)` inferring the entity class from `T`?

In case the question isn't clear, here's what I would like to achieve:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityBean<T extends BaseEntity> extends BaseBean {

    protected void loadEntity(Long entityId) {
        T entity=genericEntityService.getEntity(T, entityId); // pseudo code
    }
```

**Current solution**

```
protected void loadEntity(Long entityId) {
    ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) (superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    T entity=genericEntityService.getEntity(clazz, entityId);
}
```

I'm happy with this, as it gets me by. Down the road, I'll make the entity service type-friendly and everything should fall into place nicely.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't this impossible because of type erasure? At runtime, T will be BaseEntity and not the actual subtype.

Comment: it's possible via reflection, but costly, and generally not ideal

Comment: Kulu, you're probably referring to the first parameter in the call to getEntity(). That doesn't compile, hence my comment on pseudo code. I put it in only to illustrate what I want to achieve. I believe programmers understand code better than English. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to do this using reflection.
As some people pointed out, this adds some overhead so use it wisely.

```
protected final Class<T> getEntityClass() {
    ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) (superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return clazz;
}
```

Comment: Certainly better than what I have so far. Reflection adds a bit of overhead but in my case this is not an issue at all. I'll wait a day. If no-one addresses the question of inferring type from T, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.